# Whenever I add <mvc:annotation-driven /> in dispatcher servlet in spring mvc I get an error

Tags: spring-mvc

I was adding jQuery autocomplete for my project for `@ResponseBody` annotation I need `<mvc:annotation-driven />` tag in `dispatcher-servlet` but when I add it, I get the following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) ~[spring-beans-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) ~[spring-beans-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) ~[spring-beans-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288) ~[spring-beans-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190) ~[spring-beans-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580) ~[spring-beans-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895) ~[spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425) ~[spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276) ~[spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197) ~[spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5003) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
>       Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider
>           at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:264) ~[validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar:na]
>           at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:183) ~[spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477) ~[spring-beans-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
>           ... 21 common frames omitted
>       Dec 22, 2015 4:17:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
>       SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5003)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>       Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider
>           at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:264)
>           at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:183)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
>           ... 21 more
>       `

Answer (score 1):

Add the following dependency to your proyect:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```